# When to stop a camel context

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to Camel and was thinking of writing a new module for our project by using it.
It will be connecting to multiple endpoints like mail rss jms ftp etc for this. One thing I don't understand is when to know that its safe to stop the context (all downloads are over).

In almost all tutorials I could see till now I see

```
context.start();
Thread.sleep();
context.stop();
```

I am looking for a better way than sleeping in between to finish the camel threads

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RoutePolicy` to control routes at runtime.

For more details [Click Here](http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html)

Also check [How can I stop a route from a route](http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html)

Check the example [Controlling Start-Up and Shutdown of Routes](http://fusesource.com/docs/router/2.4/eip/BasicPrinciples-StartupShutdown.html)

If you can get the [Camel In Action](http://www.manning.com/ibsen/) read the section 
   **13.2 Starting and stopping routes at runtime**

Hope above link might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the links but arent all these about stopping routes? I was checking about CamelContext. Or stopping all added routes will bake the context too stop?

Comment: You could create CamelContext for each Route. So by doing this you get more control over there and also you can start and stop each context separately.

Comment: Also look at Graceful Shutdown : http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html. 'Its responsible for shutting down routes in a graceful manner. The other resources will still be handled by CamelContext to shutdown.'